# jQuery UI accordion issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I use the jQuery UI accordion widget, and between every item I have some space. The issue is that in IE **8** , when you slide an item, it slides fine, but it removes the space between it and the upward item. It works good in FF and other browsers, though. [image]

When I over with the mouse on that item, though, it creates that space.

I use the HTML5 doctype, but it doesn't work with others doctypes either.

Thanks.

**Edit:** Here's a [live example](http://www.godooble.info/acord/index.html).

Comment: how do you add that space in the first place ? margin ? top/bottom ? on what class/element ?

Comment: `margin:5px 0 0;` in `.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header`

Comment: It doesn't work only in IE 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try applying `margin-bottom:5px;` to `.ui-accordion-header`.

This will cause a gap between the open header and it's content, but you can fix that by removing the margin on `.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-active` and applying it to `.ui-accordion-content-active` instead.

So your css would look like this:

`.ui-accordion-header {

    margin-bottom:5px;

}

.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-active {

    margin-bottom:0;

}

.ui-accordion-content-active {

    margin-bottom:5px;

}`

That might need a bit of tweaking, but should get you mostly there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it is a weird bug that only happens when the direction of the element the margin is applied to is right to left. The solution that worked for me is to give it `direction: ltr` and then apply `direction: rtl` to it's descendents.

Again, I have no idea whatsoever why this is, but if i'd try and understand microsoft i'd kill myself. It was a lucky guess on my part, and I hope it helps someone else.