# Unable to remove space between JQuery Accordion Headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've looked at the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229723/jquery-ui-accordion-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040761/removing-space-between-accordion-panel-tab-header-and-its-content), but I can't figure out how to remove the space around the jquery-ui accordion headers in my nav bar. I've tried in chrome, ie, ff, and safari, looked with the relevant dev tools, and all seem to assure me margin and padding are 0px.

Here's what I'd like.

http://media02.hongkiat.com/jquery-ui-accordion/accordion-second-look.jpg

Sorry, I don't have the rep to post images.

So, [here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3z88b1yd/) with my basic site build.

### Html

```
    <div id="nav" style="width: 15%; float: left;">
        <div>
            <h3>Home</h3>
        </div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
            <h3>Travel</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            View trips booked through the agency. 
  <ul>
          <li>Trips Pending </li>
          <li>Trips Archived</li>
          <li>Travelers</li>
      </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>Accounts</h3>
        </div>
        <div>Select an account and view information about it, such as it's transactions, travelers associated with the account, and trips booked.</div>
        <div>
            <h3>Admin</h3>
        </div>
        <div>Generate comission reports, manage users and passwords, and deal with administrative information.</div>
    </div>
```

### Css

```
html, body
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    height:100%;
}
html
{
    background:#CCCCCC; 
}
:focus, :active 
{  
    outline: 0;  
}
#nav .ui-accordion-content 
{  
    width: 100%;  
    background-color: #f3f3f3;    
    font-size: 10pt;  
    line-height: 16pt;
}
#nav .ui-accordion-content > * 
{  
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 20px;  
}  
#nav .ui-accordion-header 
{  
    background-color: #E6E6E6;  
    margin: 0px;  
}
#nav .ui-accordion-header, .ui-accordion-content
{
    padding: 0px;
}
* 
{   
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;   
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}
```

### Js

```
$("div#nav").accordion({ heightStyle: "content" });
```

Many thanks to the helpful community of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 1em margin on h3 headers. Resetting them to 0 will remove all spacing around them.

Comment: D'oh! I'll edit that and accept this answer if/when it works.

Comment: Sure. Hope this will help. You probably didn't notice useragent default stylesheet settings, which for ie in Chrome report: 
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em; for h3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

It is a margin collapse issue, see [the MDN page about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

So, adding a small padding or transparent border in the `.ui-accordion-header` and `.ui-accordion-content` will prevent the `h3` margin to collapse.